# Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.guava (nexus)

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, nexus, pact

I'm trying to do contract testing using Pact and working in a corporate where we have a Nexus setup. I suspect that the modified Eclipse installation here uses the Nexus not the Maven repo. I created a sample Maven project, copied the following pom from a similar consumer project and just modified the provider dependency:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ctfaturaprovider</groupId>
<artifactId>contract-testing-fatura-provider</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<!-- Kontrat testing ile ilgili parent: -->
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
</parent>
<build>
    <finalName>BSA_ctfaturaprovider_ContractTestingFaturaProvider</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>update_bsa_versions</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>use-latest-snapshots</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>com.akbank.*:*</includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>akbank-maven-snapshots</id>
        <name>akbank-maven-snapshots</name>
        <url>${akbank-maven-snapshots.url}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>

    <repository>
        <id>akbank-maven-releases</id>
        <name>akbank-maven-releases</name>
        <url>${akbank-maven-releases.url}</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Kontrat testing ile ilgili dependency'ler: -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Kontrat testing ile ilgili dependency'ler sonu -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.akbank.bsa</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsa-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.akbank.bsa</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsa-unittest</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

When I save this pom, I get this error for hundreds of dependencies:

```
    Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1.0.redhat-00001

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1.0.redhat-00001

    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:329)

    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.doRecurse(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:504)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:458)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:530)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:492)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:496)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:351)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:298)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.getProjectFacade(MavenBuilder.java:154)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:89)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)

    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Failure to find com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:31.1.0.redhat-00001 in https://nexus.akbankpreprod.com/repository/maven-public-int/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-public-int has elapsed or updates are forced

    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:177)

    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:226)

    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1000)

    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:800)

    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:329)

    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)

    ... 53 more

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:31.1.0.redhat-00001 in https://nexus.akbankpreprod.com/repository/maven-public-int/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-public-int has elapsed or updates are forced

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)

    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:173)

    ... 58 more

Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:31.1.0.redhat-00001 in https://nexus.akbankpreprod.com/repository/maven-public-int/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of maven-public-int has elapsed or updates are forced

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:231)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:585)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:503)

    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)

    ... 61 more
```

I tried to Maven\Update Project with Force Update option with no luck. When I search the reported dependency, I can see it in our Nexus:
[image]

Another similar pom causes no problem in the same eclipse workspace:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>CaginGroupID</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBootFaturaConsumer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.40</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My colleague from Nexus team has reported that [a similar issue in guava-retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying/issues/104) is closed by using a different version. But I'm not direcly using the guava-retrying, it is the pact provider library (reported by a dependency analyzer used in our organization):

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project contract-testing-fatura-provider: Could not resolve dependencies for project ctfaturaprovider:contract-testing-fatura-provider:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at au.com.dius.pact.provider:junit:jar:4.4.2 -> com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:jar:2.0.0 -> com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1.0.redhat-00001: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.1.0.redhat-00001: Could not find artifact com.google.guava:guava-parent:pom:31.1.0.redhat-00001 in maven-public (https://nexus.akbankpreprod.com/repository/maven-public/)

I'm new to this maven and nexus and all the other fancy stuff. Where should I look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897084/1728856. Is is basically JBoss setup asking for a 10.+ version of Guava and Maven picking a broken one.