# "Skipping publishing verification results" error in pact for JUnit 4

Tags: junit4, pact, pact-jvm, pact-broker

When I run JUnit tests, contract tests run as expected but the results are not published to the pact broker. What do I need to do here? Here is the message I see on the console:

```
Skipping publishing verification results for source UrlSource(url=https://akbank.pactflow.io/pacts/provider/fatura-service/consumer/Mobil Mudurluk Fatura Ekibi/latest, pact=null)
```

My JUnit run configuration in Eclipse is as follows:
[image]

Here is my JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("fatura-service")
@PactUrl(
        urls="https://akbank.pactflow.io/pacts/provider/fatura-service/consumer/Mobil Mudurluk Fatura Ekibi/latest", 
        auth = @Authentication(token = "MyToken"))
//causes InitializationError: @PactBroker(consumerVersionSelectors = @VersionSelector(consumer="Mobil Mudurluk Fatura Ekibi"))
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class FaturaOdemeContractTest {
    @TestTarget
    public final Target target = new SpringBootHttpTarget();

    @State("Odenecek fatura varken")
    public void faturaVarken() {
        System.out.println("fatura varken!");
    }
    
    @State("Odenecek fatura yokken")
    public void faturaYokken() {
        System.out.println("fatura yokken!");
        FaturaOdemeMockServis mockServis = (FaturaOdemeMockServis) ContractTestConfiguration.getFaturaOdemeRestServis();
        mockServis.setFaturaVar(false);
    }
}
```

Due to organizational restrictions, I have to use JUnit 4 and the following pact provider version:

```
        <dependency>
      <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.25</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Çağın & Oğuz Nursaç: Bunu koymayınca guava bulunamadı hatası alıyoruz:
            Bkz: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74886116/one-of-the-2-eclipse-instances-on-my-pc-gives-failed-to-read-artifact-descripto
            -->
          <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed @PactUrl annotation to @PactBroker in the test class and now it works:

```
@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("fatura-service")
@PactBroker(
        url="https://akbank.pactflow.io", 
        authentication=@PactBrokerAuth(token="MyToken"))
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class FaturaOdemeContractTest {
    @TestTarget
    public final Target target = new SpringBootHttpTarget();

    @State("Odenecek fatura varken")
    public void faturaVarken() {
        System.out.println("fatura varken!");
    }
    
    @State("Odenecek fatura yokken")
    public void faturaYokken() {
        System.out.println("fatura yokken!");
        FaturaOdemeMockServis mockServis = (FaturaOdemeMockServis) ContractTestConfiguration.getFaturaOdemeRestServis();
        mockServis.setFaturaVar(false);
    }
}
```

I don't know the difference between PactUrl and PactBroker. [Documentation](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/provider/junit#download-pacts-from-a-pact-broker) tells to use PactBroker though.

Strange thing is yesterday I was getting 407 Proxy Auth required error with the same code. I guess I came across with a problem in our proxy. Lets see when we'll face another problem here.

Comment: PactURL refers to just a URL, it can be any URL. You should use the broker one annotation for any production setup

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of enabling this in Maven configuration properties, they will be propagated to JVM, see [an example](https://github.com/artemptushkin/heisenberg-pact-service/blob/master/pom.xml#L65)

Comment: This made me take another look at the documentation, thanks. But the link you gave has pact.verifier.publishResults=false. Moreover I didn't have to specify pactbroker.consumerversionselectors.tags, pactbroker.tags, or pact.provider.version. Maybe I'll need them in the future but not for the simple example I'm trying to implement now.